# Java Generics- type erasure?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

If I have a subclass which extends MySuperClass and I have the following generic class:

```
public class GenericClass<M extends MySuperClass>{

    public void aMethod(M m);

}

public class SubClass1 extends MySuperClass{}
```

then I do:

```
SubClass1 sc1 = new SubClass1();

GenericClass<MySuperClass> msc = new GenericClass<MySuperClass>();

msc.aMethod(sc1);
```

is is type erasure which determines whether the parametized type  is legal? I presume the compiler can look at `M extends MySuperClass`, look at  and determine its legal- but I wasnt sure if type erasure handled this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type erasure refers to the fact that the generic type parameters and instantiations are removed after the compilation. The compiler checks the types at compile time and then deletes all the type parameters.

Comment: Is there a name to the particular technique it uses to check the condition of M extends MySuperClass?

Comment: I think you could call it type checking!

Answer (score 3):

Compiler is the one which make sure about type safety based on generic definition in code.

[Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) removes them while compilation and

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>   Object if the type parameters are unbounded

.

Comment: So type erasure doesn't do the check on the instance parameter type- that would be just normal subtyping?

Comment: Technically yes, type erasure substitutes with their bounds defined and removes generics.

Answer (score 1):

Type-safety is something that is ensured by the compiler. The only job of the type erasure is to erase the generics portion to make the code backwards compatible with the legacy codes which were written before the generics showed up in Java. So, it's the compiler that makes sure your code is syntactically correct whether it's relation to generics or not, before the erasure comes into action.

Comment: Ok but I didnt declare that? I said GenericClass<MySuperClass> msc = new GenericClass<MySuperClass>();  ? Are you just giving additional advice?

Comment: @peroni_santo: Yes, just wanted to make sure. You were asking something about the compiler and showing some code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Hang on Bhesh, are you 100% this doesnt work? I am pretty sure if SubClass1 extends MySuperClass the above code will compile?

Comment: @peroni_santo. Correct, that will compile.

Comment: @peroni_santo: Sorry, I was thinking some other way. You are right.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: Thanks for the confirmation. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is a *runtime* artefact, when all classes are effectively "raw" (untyped).

Generics exist only during compilation. The compiler checks that the generic parameter is within bounds, but the compiled bytecode has no type information.

Comment: I thought type erasure was part of the compile-time type check process within generics?

Comment: "The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods" doesn't this mean, erasure occurs at compile time?

Comment: And I can backup my statement with following example also, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotOverload

Comment: @thinksteep yeah, ok, cool. I edited my answer to reflect that.